# Coefficients of all Dummy Factor variables in GLM

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm

I am building a Logistic Regression (in R) as follows:

```
glm_hr1 = glm(attrition_value ~ BusinessTravel+Department+Gender,              
binomial(link="logit"), data=hr1)
```

The X-variables are defined as follows:

```
BusinessTravel 
--------------
[type=Factor]
[values="Frequently","None","Rarely"]
[Ref group = "Frequently"] 

Department
----------
[type=Factor]
[values="HR","RD","Sales"
[Ref group = "HR"]

Gender
------
[type=Factor]
[values="Male","Female"]
[Ref group = "Male"]
```

summary(glm_hr1) returns the following:

```
Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)           -0.8168     0.2476  -3.298 0.000973 ***
BusinessTravelNone    -1.3738     0.2354  -5.836 5.35e-09 ***
BusinessTravelRarely  -0.6464     0.1166  -5.545 2.94e-08 ***
DepartmentRD          -0.3805     0.2387  -1.594 0.110906    
DepartmentSales        0.1187     0.2441   0.486 0.626912    
GenderFemale          -0.2086     0.1052  -1.982 0.047496 *
```

How do I get coefficients of  :
BusinessTravelFrequently
DepartmentHR
GenderMale

all in one summary ?

### What i tried ?

I used the -1 to build my model as follows:

```
glm_hr2 = glm(attrition_value ~ BusinessTravel+Department+Gender -1,
                  binomial(link="logit"), data=hr1)
```

The output of this model was:

```
Coefficients:
                         Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
BusinessTravelFrequently  -0.8168     0.2476  -3.298 0.000973 ***
BusinessTravelNone        -2.1905     0.3101  -7.063 1.63e-12 ***
BusinessTravelRarely      -1.4632     0.2333  -6.272 3.56e-10 ***
DepartmentRD              -0.3805     0.2387  -1.594 0.110906    
DepartmentSales            0.1187     0.2441   0.486 0.626912    
GenderFemale              -0.2086     0.1052  -1.982 0.047496 *
```

The (intercept) term is gone and replaced by "BusinessTravelFrequently". 
I understand why this happens.

Changing the order of formula however game me coefficients for every level
eg:

```
glm(attrition_value ~ Department+BusinessTravel+Gender -1, ....)
```

gave coefficients for all values for Department

```
glm(attrition_value ~ Gender+Department+BusinessTravel -1, ....)
```

gave coefficients for all values for Gender

Is there any way to get all coefficients for all factor variables in one summary ?

Is there any other way to do this ?